# Does the installation process automatically create a new partition?

Tags: system-installation, microsoft-windows

Does the installation process shown in elementary OS webpage automatically create a new partition?

Comment: Do you think you can flesh out your question a bit more? Are you asking because you are creating a dual boot setup? If so, with what operating system? Do you prefer that a new partition is created or that one is not? More detail will make sure you get a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your partitioning and already installed operating systems you will be presented by several options from installer.

1. **If there is free space** and you already have another operating system you will be presented with the option to "Install elementary alongside [your operating system]". The partitions to host elementary will be created from the free space on the drive.
2. Erase disk and install elementary. This option will format drive erasing all your data and create elementary partitions for clean installation as single OS.
3. To do something else. This one will take you to the partitioning wizzard that allows you to customize your set up and manually select partitions for different mounting points. [Here is detailed process of using manual partition editor.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)